# Machine learning con Keras no converge

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

Nunca converge se queda en **`"val_acc: 0.3952"`** después de mucho tiempo de entrenamiento. Incluso a veces baja el porcentaje de acierto. ¿Alguien puede decirme que cambiar para que vaya mejor?.

```py
data_entrenamiento = '/content/drive/My Drive/Reconocedor de gestos/data/entrenamiento'
data_validacion = '/content/drive/My Drive/Reconocedor de gestos/data/validacion'

"""
Parameters
"""
epocas=20
longitud, altura = 100,100
batch_size = 40
pasos = 500
validation_steps = 100
filtrosConv1 = 32
filtrosConv2 = 64
tamano_filtro1 = (3, 3)
tamano_filtro2 = (2, 2)
tamano_pool = (2, 2)
clases = 3
lr = 0.0001


##Preparamos nuestras imágenes

entrenamiento_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

entrenamiento_generador = entrenamiento_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    data_entrenamiento,
    target_size=(altura, longitud),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')

validacion_generador = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    data_validacion,
    target_size=(altura, longitud),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')



cnn = Sequential()
cnn.add(Convolution2D(filtrosConv1, tamano_filtro1, padding ="same", input_shape=(longitud, altura, 3), activation='relu'))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=tamano_pool))

cnn.add(Convolution2D(filtrosConv2, tamano_filtro2, padding ="same"))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=tamano_pool))

cnn.add(Flatten())
cnn.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
cnn.add(Dense(120, activation='relu'))
cnn.add(Dense(60, activation='relu'))
cnn.add(Dropout(0.5))
cnn.add(Dense(clases, activation='softmax'))


cnn.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",
            optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=lr),
            metrics=['accuracy'])


cnn.fit_generator(
    entrenamiento_generador,
    steps_per_epoch=pasos,
    epochs=epocas,
    validation_data=validacion_generador,
    validation_steps=validation_steps)
```

Estoy trabajando en Colab y el entrenamiento demora alrededor de 30 min. Pero nunca llega a valores deseados de acierto.

Answer (score 0):

Pues básicamente utilizas varias técnicas y supongo que habrás probado varios hiperparámetros distintos...

Lo único que te puedo decir es que para reconocimiento de gestos, que creo que es lo que tú quieres hacer, va muy bien combinar una CNN con un RNN tipo LSTM. Dan muy buenos resultados